# vue-styleguidist can not build documentation since V4.0.3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, react-styleguidist, vue-styleguidist

I'm trying to migrate to the last vue-styleguidist but since v4.0.0 i can't.
With the 3.26.2 it's working fine.

I have this error :

```
(node:11764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
```

There is a guide for the migration?
It's very strange since the babel typescript snafu everything is fine, maybe i need to add something inside babel configuration?

i'm working with :

NodeJS 10.15.1

My dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "async-validator": "^1.12.2",
    "cleave.js": "^1.5.3",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "ie11-custom-properties": "^2.3.0",
    "interactjs": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
    "mobile-device-detect": "^0.2.3",
    "normalize-wheel": "^1.0.1",
    "portal-vue": "^1.5.1",
    "throttle-debounce": "^1.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-avatar": "^2.1.8",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.4.1",
    "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-lorem-ipsum": "0.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-styleguidist": "4.0.3",
    "vue-svgicon": "^2.1.3",
    "vuebar": "^0.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "deepmerge": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint": "^4.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.4",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "favicons-webpack-plugin": "0.0.8",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "highlight.js": "^9.16.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.18.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-cucumber": "^2.0.11",
    "jest-html-reporters": "^1.2.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.0",
    "markdown-it-container": "^2.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "ora": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.10",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "ts-jest": "^24.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.4",
    "vue-markdown-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

Comment: you need to debug further to locate where is the promise set that has a `reject()` call that is not handled, or wrapped within try/catch block.  Most likely is in your code, rather than in modules. See also this issue https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist/issues/731

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try to debug further